# Java remove dynamic substring from string

Tags: java, string

I need to remove dynamic substring from string. There is a few similar topic of this theme, but noone of them helped me. I have a string e.g.:

> product test1="001" test2="abc" test3="123xzy"

and i need output:

> product test1="001" test3="123xzy"

I mean I need remove test2="abc". test2 is an unique element and can be placed anywhere in original string. "abc" is dynamic variable and can have various length. What is the fastest and the most elegant solution of this problem? Thx

Comment: Split the `String` by spaces and look in the resulting `String[]` for the one that `startsWith("test2")`

Comment: You can use regex to remove `str.replaceAll("test2=\"\\w+\"", "");`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```
String input = "product test1=\"001\" test2=\"abc\" test3=\"123xzy\"";
String result = input.replaceAll("test2=\".*?\"\\s+", "");
```

In substance: find a substring like `test2="xxxxxx"`, optionally followed by some spaces (`\\s+`) and replace it with nothing.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot. Really nice solution by using RegExp.